# Bash returns ambiguous redirect error on "do < {$1}"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently reading a programming book and have stumbled across this example

```
#!/bin/bash
# read file and create INSERT statements for MySQL
#
outfile='members.sql'
IFS=','
while read lname fname address city state zip
do
    cat >> $outfile << EOF
    INSERT INTO members (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) 
    VALUES ('$lname', '$fname', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip');
EOF
done < ${1}
```

With a members.csv file in the same directory containing

```
Monster,Cookie,123 Pastry Ln,Detroit,MI,66666
```

Bash returns

```
./test23.sh: line 11: ${1}: ambiguous redirect
```

When ran as

```
./test23.sh < members.csv
```

Everything in that file matches letter for letter what's in my programming book from ~2015.  I've tried so many different combos of {} () $ spaces and no spaces but always end up getting an ambiguous redirect error.  This is all running on /bin/bash through emacs shell, but I exited emacs and tried it through the parent LXTerminal and it still gives me the same error.  I've tried the members.csv file with and without read write and execute permissions and made sure the permissions on test23.sh are correct, I'm lost.

EDIT1:
Okay guys so it turns out the correct way to use this script across shells and bash versions is

```
done >"$1"
```

after fixing the syntax I ran it as

```
./test23.sh members.csv
```

without any additional redirection the output to members.sql was

```
    INSERT INTO members (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES 
('Blum', 'Richard', '123 Main St.', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60601');
    INSERT INTO members (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES 
('Blum', 'Barbara', '123 Main St.', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60601');
    INSERT INTO members (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES 
('Bresnahan', 'Christine', '456 Oak Ave.', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43201');
```

Comment: `<"$1"`. The curly braces are optional, but if you want reliable behavior, the quotes are not.

Comment: Also, there **is** no `$1` defined at all when you run the script the way you say you are. If you want `$1` to be `members.csv`, run it as `./test23.sh members.csv`, not `test23.sh <members.csv`: In the latter mode, `members.csv` is an instruction about the parent shell about how to connect the script's stdin before running it, **not** an argument passed to the shell it can reference after it was started.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the `<` in the invocation.  Try this:

```
./test23.sh  members.csv
```

Works for me.

EDIT: with thanks to Charles Duffy

For cross-version operability, it is also best to add quotes around the positional parameter access in the bash script, so the bottom line can become:

```
done < "${1}"
```

or

```
done < "$1"
```

Comment: That fixes it some of the time, but not always -- on some bash versions (before the relevant bug was fixed), using `<$1` or `<${1}` (as opposed to `<"$1"` or `<"${1}"`) with filenames with spaces will still throw a "ambiguous redirect" error when the redirection itself isn't quoted.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy amended the answer

Answer (score 2):

The redirection is "ambiguous" because your `$1` is empty: You never passed your script an argument at all, because `<members.csv` isn't an argument to the script -- it's an instruction to the shell about how to configure stdin *before it starts the script at all*.

You should do **either** one of two things, **but not both**:

- Pass `members.csv` as an argument, by running `./test23.sh members.csv` -- and fix the quoting on the redirection to be `<"$1"` so it's parsed correctly by all shell releases.
- Connect `members.csv` on stdin, by running `./test23.sh <members.csv` -- but then **don't** use a redirection inside the script (since redirection is already being done by the parent shell before it starts the script at all).